# JPA; Setting 'transaction-type' on annotation

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-4, transactional

I'm using Eclipselink's implementation of JPA and this is how I'm instantiating persistence context:

```
@PicketLink
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "txPersistUnit.security")
private EntityManager txEmSec;
```

this is persistence unit defitnition:

```
<persistence-unit name="txPersistUnit.security" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        ...
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.target-database" value="PostgreSQL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="true"/>
            ...
            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                      value="database"/>
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

so, you can see I am setting RESOURCE_LOCAL as a transaction-type but I'm getting this error when deploying:

```
java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : The persistence-context-ref-name [com.txsolutions.manager.PersistenceManager/txEmSec] in module [txAPI] resolves to a persistence unit called [txPersistUnit.security] which is of type RESOURCE_LOCAL. Only persistence units with transaction type JTA can be used as a container managed entity manager. Please verify your application.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Server is Glassfish 4.0.1
Question is why is glassfish not deploying this application succesfully when transaction-type set to RESOURCE_LOCAL?
I'm emphasizing that I have RESOURCE_LOCAL persistence unit in that same application on that same server deployed.

Now, when I create entity manager like this:

```
..declarations omitted..
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("txPersistUnit.security");
entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
```

it is created sucessfuly even with RESOURCE_LOCAL as for transaction type.

So all in all whats the difference between this two approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: So the error message pretty much told you exactly what's wrong. Imagine when you get an error with a less clear message.

Comment: sorry, I thought that it's obvious.. so why is not glassfish consuming this persistence unit?
Question edited, anyway...

Comment: Best description IMO: http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running your code in an JEE compliant Application Server (i.e. Glassfish), your transaction type should be JTA.

```
<persistence-unit name="txPersistUnit.security" transaction-type="JTA">
```

RESOURCE_LOCAL is generally used for Standalone Java SE applications.

Since you are using @PersistenceContext, means that you are using a **Container-Managed** entity manager/persistence context. Since it is container-managed, it requires you to set your transaction type to JTA.

I suggest you try using an **Application-Managed** persistence context. Use @PersistenceUnit to inject an instance of EntityManagerFactory, then from the factory create the entity manager. Example below.

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="txPersistUnit.security")
EntityManagerFactory emf;

....
// somewhere in your code
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: but it's not mandatory, is it? I hope you will just agree cause I have RESOURCE_LOCAL persistence unit declared and running in that very same application on that very same server.

Comment: The fact that your exception message states "Only persistence units with transaction type JTA can be used as a container managed entity manager.", means that you should set it to JTA.

Comment: In ideal world I would set it to JTA and if it deploys it's done! But it won't and I won't talk about that cause this thread is about something else. So, please, either answer my question or don't drag attention other direction. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, hope that will help resolve your issue.